# CLI command to REST API request conversion

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How to translate this:

`kubectl set image deployment/mydep mypot=img --insecure-skip-tls-verify`

into curl REST API call? I want to signal to update image without kubectl .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using **--v=9** flag, you can increases the verbosity where it shows the curl request. you can get further information [kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging)

for example,if you run the following command with **the flag** you will see following output

```
kubectl set image deployment/mydep mypot=img --insecure-skip-tls-verify --v=9
```

**kubectl request with verbosity**

```
I0319 14:07:07.912730   53546 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/suresh.vishnoi/.kube/config
I0319 14:07:07.914104   53546 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/suresh.vishnoi/.kube/config
I0319 14:07:07.921010   53546 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/suresh.vishnoi/.kube/config
I0319 14:07:07.921331   53546 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.11.0+d4cacc0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/d4cacc0" -H "Authorization: Bearer Tbg" 'https://console-openshift-test.xyz:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/mydep'
I0319 14:07:07.945798   53546 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://console-openshift-test.xyz:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/mydep 404 Not Found in 24 milliseconds
I0319 14:07:07.945861   53546 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0319 14:07:07.945871   53546 round_trippers.go:414]     Cache-Control: no-store
I0319 14:07:07.945878   53546 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0319 14:07:07.945895   53546 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 224
I0319 14:07:07.945902   53546 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Tue, 19 Mar 2019 14:07:07 GMT
```

So translated request is

```
curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.11.0+d4cacc0 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/d4cacc0" -H "Authorization: Bearer Tbg" 'https://console-openshift-test.xyz:8443/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/mydep'
```